# If a set is closed under countable unions, is it closed under countable intersections?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to think through the intuition of DeMorgan's laws.  If I have a set $\Omega$ and a sequence of subsets ($A_n$)={$X_1$, $X_2$, ...} how can I know that given the fact $\Omega$ is closed under countable unions, $\Omega$ is closed under countable intersections, or vice-versa.

Moreover - given the answer to the above, is it enough to show that $\Omega$ is closed under countable intersections OR countable unions as part of proving that $\Omega$ is a $\sigma$-algebra?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't know it, because families of sets can be closed under countable union but not under countable intersections (and viceversa). Most topologies, in fact, are like that.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, consider all the intervals of form $[0,h)$, where $h>0$, then, because it is linearly ordered under $\subseteq$, it is closed under arbitrary union(which is stronger then countable). Now take all the members in the form of $[0,1/n)$ for natural $n$, the intersection is the singleton $\{0\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false. Consider as $\Omega$ the family of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ whose complement is finite plus the empty set.

Then $\Omega$ is closed under arbitrary unions (in particular, countable unions), but it is easy to find a countable family whose intersection doesn't belong to $\Omega$: take $A_n=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1,2,\dots,n\}$; then $\bigcap_n A_n=\{0\}\notin\Omega$.

Closure under countable unions implies closure under countable intersections if the family is closed under complements (this follows from De Morgan’s laws).

Answer (score 4):

For a small example:

$\mathcal{F}=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$ is closed under unions... (*Each of $\{1\}\cup\{1\},\{1\}\cup\{2\},\{1\}\cup\{1,2\},\dots$ etc... are elements of $\mathcal{F}$*)

...however it is not closed under intersections.  (*$\{1\}\cap\{2\}=\emptyset\notin\mathcal{F}$*)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is *if* it is also closed under complements.

Suppose $A \in \Omega$ and $B \in \Omega$.

Then  $A^c \in \Omega$ and $B^c \in \Omega$.

Then $(A^c \cup B^c)^c = A \cap B \in \Omega$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the family of sets of natural numbers with at least seventeen elements.

The union of any number of such sets still has at least seventeen elements. But the *intersection* ...